# bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in

Tags: php

Para el código este, me da este error, no se como solucionar este error, parece que es en bind

> mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in

Aqui es donde hago el insert para preparar  la consulta:

```
 // Insertar datos
    $insertar = $conn->prepare('
        INSERT INTO alojamientos (
            localizacion,
            numeroHabitaciones,
            incluidaMediaPension,
            fumador,
            ninios,
            mascotas

        ) VALUES (
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?,
            ?

        )
    ');
```

Y este es el codigo del bind

```
 /* Asignamos la conversión para poder pasar por referencia una variable */
    $incluidaMediaPension = empty($_POST["incluidaMediaPension"]) ? 0 : 1;
    $fumador = empty($_POST["fumador"]) ? 0 : 1;
    $ninios = empty($_POST["ninios"]) ? 0 : 1;
    $mascotas = empty($_POST["mascotas"]) ? 0 : 1;        
$consulta->bind_param(
        'siiiii',
        $_POST["localizacion"],
        $_POST["numeroHabitaciones"],
        $incluidaMediaPension,
        $fumador,
        $ninios,
        $mascotas

    );
    if ($insertar->execute() === true) {
        die("inserted data");
    } else {
        die("failed: " . $consulta->error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Agrega la línea de código donde escribes el INSERT

Comment: hecho, ya lo agregué

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definiste la prepared statement `insertar` pero intentas utilizar `consulta`.